# How to store availability of practitioner (day of week, and time of day) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am developing an application which will keep track of various information about medical practitioners that are affiliated with my place of work. One thing that we are tracking, is their availability by time of day (morning, afternoon, and evening) for each day of the week (monday - sunday). Additionally we will store an optional comment about the practitioners availability, something like "Does not work during full moon."

The input/display form for this information will be table with days of the week as column headers, and times of the day as row headers. Check boxes will indicate whether the practitioner is available during the specified time.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to store this information in the database. The most obvious solution to create a table with 24 columns (21 for 7 days * 3 times, 1 as the primary key, and 1 for the foreign key referring to the practitioner, and 1 for the comment). Which is a crappy table, but at least it's easy to select and update.

Another solution is to create a table with attributes:

- practitioner_id :: int (foreign key and primary key)
- day_of_week :: int (primary key) (could also be Enum, but I don't think SQL Server has that type)
- morning :: bit
- afternoon :: bit
- evening :bit

That's a less ugly table, but it will be a pain to update, since I would have to have a separate update statement for each day of the week. The comment would also have to be stored outside of this table.

Yet another solution may be to have one column for each day of the week, with the datatype being BLOB (or whatever SQL Server's version of that is). And then store the time information as an array of size three. But I'm sure this breaks every rule of good database design. This would also limit the effectiveness of select queries.

Any ideas as to how to store this data?

EDIT:

To clarify, we are only interested in what their average week schedule is. Things like holidays and vacations can be ignored.

On the front end, the information will be displayed as a grid, with columns representing days of the week, and rows representing times of the day.

This information may need to be searchable. For example, we may want to pull up a report of all practitioners who work on Monday evenings.

Comment: If a practitioner is available on Monday afternoons, does that mean they will be available EVERY SINGLE Monday afternoon? So you do not need to account for holidays, vacation, etc? Anyway don't even think about arrays or blobs. These are discrete pieces of information and belong in individual columns - do you really think a blob or array will be easier to manage? Why?

Comment: Are you needing to display the schedule, or check if a given time is within a practitioner's availability, or something else? I.e, what's the application?

Comment: Personally I would prefer the solution to store 24 columns (all bit fields). One record for each practitioner sounds pretty good - looking forward - any select statement will be much easier with one row for each person - than up to seven rows for each one!

Comment: When you say "the information will be displayed as a grid", will the grid show availability for all practitioners, or is it one grid per practitioner?

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer: *"any select statement will be much easier with one row for each person"* I seriously doubt that. Write the easy query that shows all persons that are available 2 or 3 afternoons, 1 or 2 mornings and 3 to 5 evenings but cannot work in Monday mornings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following design, a many-to-many relationship.

```
table: practitioners
- practitioner_id

table: schedule_blocks
- schedule_block_id

table: practitioners_to_schedules
- practitioner_id
- schedule_block_id
```

When I design, I'm using looking at the lifetime of the system and what are the probable changes to be added.  This design requires a little more effort upfront, but saves effort over time.

A record is only written to the practitioners_to_schedules table when a practitioner is available.  This could reduce the size of the table and can result a denser number of records per data/index page.

One advantage of the above design is that it does not hard-code the current schedule "chunking" into the schema.  If in the future, the system were to break the "chunks" down into hours, the table schema would not change, just the contents of the tables.

Another advantage is this lends itself to the concept of effective dates.  A physician is available every Monday morning, but is unavailable next week.  Add effective_date and end_date to the relation table and the functionality is supported.

This lends itself to a relatively simple and indexing scheme.  Two indexes on practitioners_to_schedules and you can report on most options efficiently.  Depending on which reads are most common, you can decide which id to use for the clustered index.

Comment: The requirements changed, and now we're only tracking days of the week, and not times of the day. But if the original requirements were still in place, this would be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your second table design will meet your needs better:

```
practitioner_id :: int (foreign key and primary key)
day_of_week :: int (primary key)
morning :: bit
afternoon :: bit
evening :bit
```

Comment: It's better to keep the data more normalized than the denormalized 21 column version from the OP. Remember, your database doesn't need to (shouldn't) look like the shape of the models (classes) you code against. You just need a way to map between the models and the databases. You may need multiple models as well for editing which are different from those you use for reporting.